# How can I add a timer in the memory game?

Tags: python, timer

If I want to add a timer in my game. I want it to appear on the screen from the beginning of the game to the end, what code should I add? and where should I add the code?

This is the game and I think I should add the additional code on line 48, which is the "def main()".
http://inventwithpython.com/pygame/chapter3.html

```
def main():
    global FPSCLOCK, DISPLAYSURF
    pygame.init()
    FPSCLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
    DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT))
```

Comment: Did you try searching this site for `[pygame] timer`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python's [`clock()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/time_clock.htm) method to create timers.